# show a recursive list of files modified since i last logged in

Tags: linux, find

I am trying to figure out how to use find to show a list of all files in my current directory and lower that have been modified since my current terminal session was started.

Obviously a recursive find is to be used, but how do i delineate the results to just show files that are modified since i logged in? do i check them against some other file that is always modified on login? Is there a built in way?

say some thing like:
`find . -newer 'xxxx'` where xxxx is some file that gets modified at the start of a terminal session. But what file would work for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no specific file you can use for this, but it's easy to add your own.

In your `.profile` or `.bash_profile` or whatever you could do something like

```
TIMEFILE=$HOME/.lastlogin
[[ ! -f $TIMEFILE ]] && touch $TIMEFILE
find $HOME -newer $TIMEFILE
touch $TIMEFILE
```

The `[[` line is there to prevent `find` from complaining if the file doesn't exist.

Edit:  Ah, sorry, I may have slightly misunderstood your question.  You may want to run the command at any time, so in this case you could just have this in your `.bash_profile`

```
touch $HOME/.lastlogin
```

And now from the command line

```
find $HOME -newer $HOME/.lastlogin
```

You can reset the timer at any time by `touch`ing the file again.

Comment: ok so each time my shell is invoked it makes a new file and then uses it as the time baseline?

Comment: It's important to do the `find` _before_ the `touch`.  So you use the _previous_ timestamp file (ie your previous login) for the comparison, then update the timestamp when it completes.  Or if you just want to run the command at any time, the `touch` command in your `.bash_profile` is sufficient, and you can run the `find` command at any time.

Comment: Ah, I may have slightly misunderstood your question, so I added some additional discussion to the answer.

Comment: This makes sense thank you. Just curious, is there some other, built in way to search for files modified since login? My original assumption was find but i want to make sure i am not overthinking something simple.

Answer (score 1):

In Bash you could calculate the time that has passed since you logged in, with `last`.

```
TIMEDIFF=$(( ( $(date --date="$(last -1 | head -n 1 | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f3-6)" +%s) - $(date +%s) ) / 60 ))
```

Note that this will yield a negative number. (That's useful for the next step.)

Then you add the time difference with the `-mmin` parameter to the `find` command:

```
find . -mmin $TIMEDIFF
```

Of course you can also make it a one-liner.

Comment: This doesn't work for me as the find just shows everything that exists. I also get weird results from the code in that variable:

 TIMEDIFF=$(( ( $(date --date="$(last -1 | head -n 1 | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f3-6)" +%s) - $(date +%s) ) / 60 ))

date: invalid date ‘134.29.149.192 Wed Jun 27’

Comment: Fixed the oneliner, but requires GNU grep: TIMEDIFF=$(( ( $(date --date="$(last -1 $(whoami) | head -n 1 | grep -oP '\w{3} \w{3} \d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}')" +%s) - $(date +%s) ) / 60 )). Alternatively, if you're using bash, the $SECONDS variable might help you out more: TIMEDIFF="-$(( $SECONDS / 60 ))"